# Strange behavior in layout of my ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbaractivity

I got a problem that I didnt seen yet. Sometimes layout xml file in my ActionBarActivity shows a strange behavior.  The background color of some linear layout and custom styled actionbar shows different shades of applied color. Sometimes it works perfectly as expected. Here is the screenshots of my problem.

**Expected result**

[image]

**Sometimes I getting like this**
[image]

**my layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button_selector"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/add_food"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/theme_red" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <!-- Time Block -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/theme_red"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timeTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/time"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:weightSum="5" >

                <!--
                <wheel.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/day"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2.3" />

                <wheel.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/hour"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".9" />

                <wheel.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/mins"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".9" />

                <wheel.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/ampm"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".9" />
                -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Item Block -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/theme_red"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/item"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="3" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/foodListSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addFoodItems" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/addFoodItems"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_button_selector"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/add_food_item"
                    android:src="@drawable/add_food" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Quantity Block -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/theme_red"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/quantityTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/quantity"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/quantityNoSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/quantityPieceSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**my custom actionbar**

```
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/theme_red</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/theme_red</item>
        <item name="android:alwaysDrawnWithCache">true</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle|showHome|homeAsUp</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

These problems only appears in some devices. I hope somebody can help me out from this problem.

Comment: Did you check you resources. i think there is a problem with multi layout resources "@color/theme_red". So check them..

Comment: Yes I've checked. But no duplicates for theme_red

Comment: Just try to put static red color code instead of "@color/theme_red".

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/add_food"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/theme_red" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!-- Time Block -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.30"
                android:background="@color/theme_red"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timeTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/time"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.70">

                <!--
                <wheel.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/day"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2.3" />

                <wheel.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/hour"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".9" />

                <wheel.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/mins"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".9" />

                <wheel.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/ampm"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".9" />
                -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Item Block -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.30"
                android:background="@color/theme_red"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/item"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.70" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/foodListSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addFoodItems" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/addFoodItems"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_button_selector"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/add_food_item"
                    android:src="@drawable/add_food" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Quantity Block -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.30"
                android:background="@color/theme_red"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/quantityTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/quantity"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.70">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/quantityNoSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/quantityPieceSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button_selector"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```